# Recover unsaved project I've been working on for months?

Tags: workflow, blend-files

I misclicked save instead of save as due to jerking my mouse. I was planning to exit out of blender, so the project reverts to default. Lost two character models. Autosave was my backup plan, but it only saved a recent version of my project. How can I recover my file?

Comment: Unfortunately that's why you should keep frequent backups!

Comment: Look for a \*.blend1 file in the same directory. Before the save command is executed Blender renames an existing file with the same name to *.blend1* so it is not overwritten and not lost.

Comment: @Blunder I was about to add that but run out of editing time! You can also increase the number of backups saved under Preferences > Save & Load > Blend files > Recent Versions. - It won't help this time but might prevent disasters in future!

Comment: @JohnEason I don't know how to backup more frequently.

Comment: Edit > Preferences > Save & Load tab. Make sure that Auto Save is checked and you can choose the Timer frequency which defaults to 1 minute. Under Blend Files, Save Versions is 1 by default but you can increase that. However, if it's saving backups automatically every minute, you'll end up with quite a few files to look through if you want to restore at a particular time! If you don't have Autosave Preferences checked (click the bottom-left corner hamburger icon), you'll need to use Save Preferences before closing that window.

Comment: You can search `temp` directory on your system for blender-like backup files. This usually works for crashes but might be worth trying finding something there.

Comment: @JohnEason This helped, but the solution isn't perfect because recently my autosave backup became unusable after a PC freeze.

Comment: I like to work on blend files in a cloud storage service that keeps a version history. dropbox, icloud, google drive... every time I get up from my computer I ask myself “if my computer burst into flames, could I keep working on the project elsewhere?”

Answer (score 0):

Looking for .blend1 file OR File - Recover - Autosave